# Python: How to check if the first item in each sublist in a list is a consecutive number and the second number is the same?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm a beginner so bear with my inability to explain this. I'm trying to make a conditional statement in order to check the positioning of mouse-clicks. For example, I'm allowing the user to click anywhere on the screen and these points (*x*-coordinate, *y*-coordinate) are being put into a `list`. However, my list will contain *(x, y)* tuples, where *x* and *y* each range between 0 and 8.

I am trying to write a conditional statement in which at least four consecutive *x*-coordinates exist for the same *y*-coordinate. It is rechecking it after every click is added into the list.

The code needs to be able to check ALL the *x*'s in the tuples, and look for the consecutive numbers even if they are in the wrong order.

Example:  `List = [(1,2), (3,7), (4,2), (3,1), (5,2), (2,2), (3,2)]`

In this example, there are 5 consecutive mouse clicks where x=n+1 for y=2
so my conditional statement should identify this as *True*.

I've tried so many different things like dictionaries and separate lists but I don't really know how to do this.  I currently tried this:

```
# python
list2=[point[0] for point in List]
for n in list2:
   for column in range(0,8):
      if (List[n][column] and List[n+1][column] and List[n+2][column] and List[n+3][column])in List:
           self.__win= True
      else:
           self.__win=False
self.update()
```

the List is made in some other method so I was trying to take the first point in each sublist, put it into list2, use that as n for my if statement, and then have a second for statement checking the columns. However, it says index out of range, because theres nothing in my list at first when I first run the program because there are no clicks!!

Comment: is list size always 8?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the coordinates only go from 0 to 8

Comment: and you want any four of eight to be equal in consecutive manner?

Comment: can you provide some more pass cases and fail cases?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding clicks kind of in a continuous stream perhaps it would be better to just keep track of the last click and the collection of good consecutives until the criteria matches.

You could use function static variables for this appended via a decorator to the function that estimates whether you've had or not 4 correct consecutive clicks.

A detailed example below:

```
clicks = [(1,2), (3,7), (4,2), (3,1), (5,2), (2,2), (3,2)]
good_clicks = [(1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2)]
good_not_first_clicks = [(3,4), (5,5), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2), (7,8)]


def static_var(varname, value):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate


@static_var("consecutives", [])
@static_var("pre_click", None)
def add_click(click):
    if add_click.pre_click is None:
        add_click.pre_click = click
        add_click.consecutives.append(click)
        return False

    if add_click.pre_click[0] < click[0] and add_click.pre_click[1] == click[1]:
        add_click.consecutives.append(click)

        if len(add_click.consecutives) == 4:
            add_click.consecutives = [click]
            return True
        elif len(add_click.consecutives) > 4:
            add_click.consecutives = [click]
            return False
    else:
        add_click.consecutives = [click]

    add_click.pre_click = click

    return False


print("FIRST ATTEMPT")
for click in clicks:
    print(add_click.consecutives, add_click(click))

print("\nSECOND ATTEMPT")
for click in good_clicks:
    print(add_click.consecutives, add_click(click))

print("\nTHIRD ATTEMPT")
for click in good_not_first_clicks:
    print(add_click.consecutives, add_click(click))
```

Which executed will produce:

```
FIRST ATTEMPT
[(1, 2)] False
[(1, 2)] False
[(3, 7)] False
[(4, 2)] False
[(3, 1)] False
[(5, 2)] False
[(2, 2), (3, 2)] False

SECOND ATTEMPT
[(2, 2), (3, 2)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2)] True

THIRD ATTEMPT
[(4, 2)] False
[(3, 4)] False
[(5, 5)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)] False
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2)] True
[(4, 2)] False
```